# How to Show or Load Data from CSV file into list in flutter

Tags: csv, flutter, dart

I want to show data from CSV file into list.
what is the proper way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put *.csv file into asset directory, install CSV plugin and run pub get. Than follow the given code. it will print data. you need to call loadAsset() function to see the result.

```dart
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

 List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/Book1.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);

    data = csvTable;
    print(data);
```

to show data on Flutter UI add given code to body. it will create a table to show data from *.csv file.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Table(
                border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
                children: data.map((item) {
                  return TableRow(
                      children: item.map((row) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          row.toString(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList());
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]